# When should I use barrels instead of using Applied Energetics?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-applied-energistics

Applied Energetics is awesome. It stores everything. However, sometimes I have a *lot* of stuff, and need a lot of space. In that case, would it be better to use an Extradimensional Barrel or still use my AE storage system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you have a lot of the same stuff (cobblestone, dirt, etc.) an Extradimensional Barrel is great (you can connect it to the AE system with a storage bus), but when you have a lot of different stuff the AE drive rules (8 drives with up to 64 types in each).